# poll system call timeout

Tags: linux, system-calls, strace

Attaching `strace` shows a lot of these messages:

```
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)

poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)

poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)

poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
```

How can I find what file the program is trying to access that causes `poll` system call to timeout?

`strace` generates a lot of messages which make it hard to debug

Comment: Depends. What are these six fds? Did you find matching calls to `open()` in the trace log?

Comment: I don't know. WHat does that mean?

Comment: Can you explain the steps in a reply? What do you mean by matching?

Comment: Assuming these file descriptors are actually files (as opposed to sockets or pipes), there should be calls to the `open()` syscall in the output of `strace`. You would have to look for the ones that returned `5`, `6`, etc. in order to determine which files were opened.

Answer (score 30):

> How can I find what file the program is trying to access that causes poll system call to timeout?

Invoke:

```
lsof -p <pid>
```

And see what the file descriptors in question refer to.

You can also take a look into `proc` filesystem on Linux:

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd
```

Answer (score 0):

ls -l /proc//fd/ -> You will get the corresponding node Id. 
ss -p | grep  -> you will get the socket file path the fd belongs to.