# Poll system call - is this infiniband communication?

Tags: mpi, file-descriptor, infiniband

I have a place in my `openmpi` (compiled for `infiniband` usage) code where there is no progress output and `strace` on one of the processes shows this:

```
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=23, events=POLLIN}], 3, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
```

over and over again. As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018981/poll-system-call-timeout) I ran `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` and I see a couple of `socket`s and `/dev/infiniband/` links. Is this system call indicative of interprocess communication over `infiniband`? How can I verify this or further debug what is happening in the code at this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that poll returns with a timeout only means that the process is waiting for some communication event to occur. This [openmpi faq page](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging) lists some ways to debug.